# Set draft depending on operating system

Tags: conditionals, ifplatform

I'm working on two different operating systems - MacOS and Windows. While the main part of my work is done on OSX, I sometimes switch to windows for several reasons.

Problem is: Windows and OSX don't share the same prerequisites e.g. Windows does not have `pygments` installed, which is used for highlighting source code with `minted`. 
Is it possible to set `draft` depending on the system I'm currently using?

I already found the `ifplatform` package, but I'm not sure, how to use this with document options.

Comment: you probably don't need a document option but just `\ifwindows \usepackage[draft]{minted} \else \usepackage{minted} \fi` ?

Comment: install pygments on windows?

Comment: @percusse that's what I do but doesn't seem in the spirit of the question:-)

Comment: I don't have permissions to install something on this system

Comment: Note that `minted` already loads `ifplatform`.

Comment: @egreg ya, but I have to load it, in order to use it for configuring `minted`, right?

Comment: @Rico Yes; I checked whether doing `\ifwindows\minted@draftrue\fi` after loading `minted` suffices, but it doesn't.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this worked. Would you be so kind and add this as an answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The event is starting in a few hours, do you mind if i png you now and ask you to add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since David is not responding:

His answer worked for me:

```
\ifwindows 
   \usepackage[draft]{minted} 
 \else 
   \usepackage{minted}
\fi
```